# What does the "h" "k" and "(5.2.2.02,6)" mean in dibenzo(h,k)-4-oxatricyclo(5.2.2.02,6)undec-8,10- diene-3, 5-dione?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, synthesis

I am preparing to do an experiment that involves synthesizing dibenzo(h,k)-4-oxatricyclo(5.2.2.0<sup>2,6</sup>)undec-8,10- diene-3, 5-dione via a Diels-Alder reaction.

Could someone please explain the nomenclature for this molecule? Specifically, what do "h", "k" and 5.2.2.0<sup>2,6</sup> mean?

Below is the reaction:
[image]

Comment: I'm not very good with organic chemistry but this got me thinking, and after checking [this](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_229.htm#Ind0tj_xq) I think the [h,k] denotes which positions the oxatricyclo~ group is bonded to the "main" ring. Maybe this is clearer: http://i.imgur.com/Iudam83.png

Comment: @Molx Interesting, but unfortunately, it's not even wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The systematic (but not necessarily preferred) name **tricyclo[5.2.2.0<sup>2,6</sup>]undecane** describes the structure of octahydro-1⁠*H*-4,7-ethanoindene (see [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/35861/7951) on how to name tricyclo compounds):

[image: tricyclo[5.2.2.02,6]undecane]

Expanding the name from tricyclo[5.2.2.0<sup>2,6</sup>]undecane to **4-oxatricyclo[5.2.2.0<sup>2,6</sup>]undec-8,10-diene-3,5-dione** adds the functional groups, which leads to the structure of 3a,4,7,7a-tetrahydro-4,7-etheno-2-benzofuran-1,3-dione:

[image: 4-oxatricyclo[5.2.2.02,6]undec-8,10-diene-3,5-dione]

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*, isomers of fused polycyclic ring systems are distinguished by lettering each peripheral side of the parent component using the italic letters *a*, *b*, *c*, etc., beginning with *a* for the side numbered ‘1,2’, *b* for ‘2,3’, etc.
For example:

[image: azulene]    [image: benzo[a]azulene]    [image: dibenzo[e,h]azulene]

Accordingly, fusion of two benzene rings to the above-mentioned parent structure 4-oxatricyclo[5.2.2.0<sup>2,6</sup>]undec-8,10-diene-3,5-dione at the relevant sides yields the name **dibenzo[*h*,*k*]-4-oxatricyclo[5.2.2.0<sup>2,6</sup>]undec-8,10-diene-3,5-dione**.
(Note that this name does not necessarily correspond to the *preferred* IUPAC nomenclature and notation.)

Answer (score 5):

Regarding Loong's correct answer, unsaturated fused polycyclic hydrocarbon azulene atom numbering<sup>1</sup> (top left), and peripheral bond (edge) letter “numbering” for fusion nomenclature (top right).

Below is the skeleton of your product (without the two fused benzenes, before the dibenzo[…]… nomenclatoric operation), atom numbering<sup>2</sup> (bottom left).

However, letter “numbering” of edges (bonds) is not used for polycyclic saturated hydrocarbon nomenclature, as the names are constructed in a different way<sup>3</sup> (also there's no single continuous edge loop defined). But if someone would try to do that similarly for unsaturated polycyclic ring nomenclature, he/she would come with bond letter-ing, including those ***h**,**k*** (bottom right).

[image: Fig.1]

It's really strange that this very notable chemical seller uses this weird, wrongly constructed name as (the only) [product](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/s958166) name ([webarchived](http://web.archive.org/web/20161013174325/http://www.sigmaaldrich.com:80/catalog/product/aldrich/s958166?lang=en&region=US)) (or did you see it elsewhere?); see e.g. [PubChem record](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/138503) for alternatives. (By the way, I think that a decent name, although maybe not preferred as well, is **3,4-(9,10-dihydroanthracene-9,10-diyl)oxolane-2,5-dione**, maybe yet better with bridging nomenclature using prefixes like benzeno, furano, epipyrano, …: **11,15-dihydro-9,10-[3,4]furanoanthracene-12,14-dione** (see e.g. examples in BB2013 P-25.4.4.1))

---

1. *Note that the non-peripheral, fusion atom numbers are appended with Latin letters, but these are unrelated to edge (bond) letters.*
2. *Note the different numbering for saturated polycyclic hydrocarbons, starting at “fusion” (wrong term in this context), or bridges junction; also no letters added anywhere.*
3. *The dibenzo derivative would be named as an unsaturated pentacyclic hydrocarbon, pentacyclo[6.6.5.0<sup>2,7</sup>.0<sup>9,14</sup>.0<sup>15,19</sup>]nonadeca‐2(7),3,5,9(14),10,12‐hexaene.*